# Abrir um arquivo utilizando função secundária

Tags: c, arquivo, ponteiro

Preciso criar uma função que "aponte" um ponteiro de arquivo para um determinado arquivo na memória do computador. Consegui fazer isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void abre(FILE*);
void procedimento();

int main ()
{
    procedimento();

    return 0;
}

void abre(FILE* arq)
{
    arq = fopen("testando.txt", "w");
}

void procedimento()
{
    FILE* arq = NULL;

    abre(arq);

    fprintf(arq, "Ola mundo!");

}
```

O programa executa no terminal, não ocorrem erros. O arquivo é criado, mas ele fica em branco. A mensagem do "fprintf" não é gravada.

OBS: Primeiramente eu estava fazendo o código sem apontar o arquivo para NULL, entretanto li que ocorrem erros quando você usa um ponteiro sem apontá-lo para algum endereço de memória e isso realmente acontecia. O terminal travava durante a execução.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema não é a função de abertura ou escrita no arquivo e sim a passagem de parâmetro por referência que está tentando fazer. A variável `arq` é um ponteiro para um arquivo e quando se passa um ponteiro como parâmetro por referência é necessário usar ponteiro para ponteiro a final de contas `arq` tem um endereço.
Você pode fazer de duas maneiras.
Usando ponteiro para ponteiro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void abre(FILE** arq);
void procedimento();

int main ()
{
    procedimento();

}

void abre(FILE** arq)
{
    *arq = fopen("testando.txt", "w");
}

void procedimento()
{
    FILE* arq = NULL;

    abre(&arq);

    fprintf(arq, "Ola mundo!");

}
```

Ou declarando `arq` como uma variável global:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void abre();
void procedimento();
FILE* arq = NULL;

int main ()
{
    procedimento();

}

void abre()
{
    arq = fopen("testando.txt", "w");
}

void procedimento()
{

    abre(arq);

    fprintf(arq, "Ola mundo!");

}
```